# printing sequence in rml surprises me

Tags: odoo, rml

Kindly take a look at this code and correct me if i am wrong

The following code

```
 <blockTable style="Table4">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="P26">
              <seqReset id="seq_1"/>
      </para>
    </td>
 </tr>
</blockTable>
<blockTable style="Table4">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="P26">  <seq id="seq_1"/>.<seq id="seq_2"/>   </para>
    </td>
 </tr>
</blockTable>
```

**Outputs:**

1..1

1..2

1..3

Whereas the following code

```
 <blockTable style="Table4">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="P26">
              <seqReset id="seq_1"/>
      </para>
    </td>
 </tr>
</blockTable>
<blockTable style="Table4">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="P26">  <seq id="seq_1"/><seq id="seq_2"/>   </para>
    </td>
 </tr>
</blockTable>
```

**Outputs:**

11

12

13

**What i actually require is**

1.1

1.2

1.3

I am implementing this report for openerp7 module. Kindly Clarify. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Hi it's a bit late but maybe it will still help you (or others) :-)

Try to set some simple not influencing tags around your texts/strings (which come right after your sequence) like:

```
<seq id="seq_1"/><font>.</font><seq id="seq_2"/>
```

or

```
<seq id="seq_1"/><font>:</font>
```

I didn't try other tags so far, but i guess you can use others, too.